# how to write from clause in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Need to write the below Query with in the Procedure (use in parameter)

```
 SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.ID,
               b.table_name,
               b.creation_date,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.table_name ORDER BY b.creation_date desc) as date_ranking
     FROM  xxc_history a,
           xxc_history_details b
    WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
           AND name = P_NAME)
    WHERE   date_ranking = 1;
```

And I need to call this procedure in some place. I'm using 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: You can call functions in a query, but not procedures.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is this displays all the rows and records..:)

Comment: This is related to the Oracle form Query and i need to write in the Procedure or function and need to call those program in the Button in the ORacle Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this query in a function and return the result set as a sysrefcursor

An example of refcursor approach is given below:

```
 create or replace function f_example (p_name varchar2) return sys_refcursor is

     v_sysrefcursor sys_refcursor;

  Begin
    open v_sysrefcursor for ( SELECT *
                              FROM (SELECT a.ID,
                               b.table_name,
                               b.creation_date,
                               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.table_name ORDER BY                b.creation_date desc) as date_ranking
                             FROM  xxc_history a,
                                   xxc_history_details b
                             WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
                             AND name = P_NAME)
                             WHERE   date_ranking = 1);

                             return v_sysrefcursor;
  end f_example ;
```

To call this function in another procedure p_calling_proc:

```
  create or replace procedure p_calling_proc
   is

    v_sysrefcursor sys_refcursor;
     v_name varchar2(32);

  begin 
    v_name :='Vishad';

    v_sysrefcursor :=f_example(v_name);

 end p_calling_proc;
```

Hope it helps

Vishad

Comment: Hi, Here is the parameter i am passing " AND name = P_NAME" , and i must use IN Parameter

Comment: and need to call this function/procedure in another procedure